# Reverse DNS error

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, dns-zone, cloudflare

Today I changed my DNS and nameservers to Cloudflare. After that, pingdom gave some strange DNS errors. I searched the internet but couldn't find a solution. The errors are:

```
Could not find reverse address for 64.233.162.26 (26.162.233.64.in-addr.arpa.).

PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).

Could not find reverse address for 64.233.189.27 (27.189.233.64.in-addr.arpa.).

PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).

Could not find reverse address for 2404:6800:4008:c07:0:0:0:1b (b.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7.0.c.0.8.0.0.4.0.0.8.6.4.0.4.2.ip6.arpa.).

PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).

Could not find reverse address for 64.233.189.26 (26.189.233.64.in-addr.arpa.).

PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).

Could not find reverse address for 2404:6800:4008:c07:0:0:0:1b (b.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7.0.c.0.8.0.0.4.0.0.8.6.4.0.4.2.ip6.arpa.).

PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).
```

Could someone help please?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem you are having? This is not an indication of a real problem.

Comment: It's a warning given by Pingdom. The website is still working, but I think something has to be changed? I'm a bit new to DNS so I'm not sure..

Comment: What relation do these addresses have to your own services? The addresses belong to Google, they have the ability to set `PTR` records for the addresses.

Comment: Thank you. But who do I need to contact to fix it? I don't know the addresses..

Answer (score 1):

DNS servers have cache, each change take time to be fully functional for all DNS servers. It may be fix in few hours.
You can try `nslookup -type=ns 64.233.162.26` to get a non cached answer

Comment: It seams that cloudfare does not support reverse DNS. You can contact your ISP or your web server hoster.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment earlier, the addresses mentioned in the question belong to Google and therefore it's ultimately up to Google whether these addresses have a reverse `PTR` record or not.

I haven't really dug into what exactly all of these addresses may be (maybe Pingdom made that information available to you?) but for instance `64.233.189.26` appears to be one of the addresses associated with `ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM`. Am I correct to assume that you use Google Apps with this domain?

All in all, is the lack of reverse records actually causing any problems at all for you? If so, contact the service provider (Google).

Comment: It's not causing any problems at this moment but I want to prevent them ;) I think I don't use Google Apps so I don't know where the errors come from. Thanks for your answer!